# iPad, How to make an in-app settings page

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, popup, settings

In my iPad app, I need to pop up a settings page which has the same look-and-feel as the Settings app. I noticed that a lot other apps has that such as [DocAS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/docas-lite-pdf-notes-document/id451036875?mt=8) and the official mail app, so I was wondering if there's an official API or a third party lib for that.

I know I can build a view from scratch, just wondering if I could avoid rebuilding the wheel, Thanks guys~

p.s. I'm not looking for popover view, just for the record.

Comment: "popup" is overly specific... might want to modify your title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you are going to have to build the view from scratch, but the Settings view you are talking about is built using the Interface Builder widgets, so it should be pretty quick to do in IB.

Comment: Even the background image is abailable in IB, so yeah.